# Не удается найти "Java"

Tags: php, java

Не могу понять почему пишет

> Не удается найти "java". Проверьте, правильно ли указано имя  и повторите попытку.

В "системные переменные среды", пробовал добавлять путь к java но безрезультатно

```
$cmd = 'java -jar C:/start.jar';
if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
  pclose(popen("start /B ".$cmd, "r"));
} else {
  exec($cmd." > /dev/null &", $PID);
}
```

Comment: а если в командной строке запустить? находит?

Comment: да, находит ...

Comment: запускаете под одним и тем же пользователем?

Comment: Да, пользователь 1 - Администратор. Отключал uac думал проблема в правах, но нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как запускал на Локальном сервере используя Open Server, не учел что терминал в нем запускается не стандартный а conemu, поэтому решения данной проблемы:
**Настройки** -> **Сервер** -> **Настройка использования переменной Path** 
 -> установил в положение "Свой Path + userdata/config/path.txt". Добавил путь к Java и все работает